# Best practice for nested Python module imports

Tags: python, python-import

Suppose I have a Python module "main.py":

```
import math           # from the standard Python library
import my_own_module

...

foo = math.cos(bar)
```

And I also need to import the standard math module in "my_own_module.py":

```
import math

...

baz = math.sin(qux)
```

In this case I think `import math` in "main.py" is redundant and can be omitted.

What's best practice in this case:

1. Omit `import math` from "main.py" becuase it's redundant? Or,
2. Keep `import math` in "main.py" to clarify that the code in that module requires it?

Comment: (1) is not an option, the import is not redundant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reference to `math.cos` in `main.py` means that `import math` is required in `main.py`, regardless of whether `my_own_module.py` imports it or not.  It is not redundant, and it cannot be omitted (and if you try to omit it, you'll get an error).

Answer (score 3):

```
import math
```

does something *else* than simply *including the full text of one file into the other*.

It introduces a new *namespace* with the name `math`, and this `math` name will be known in your *current namespace*.

If you omit the

```
import math
```

from your `main.py` file, your command

```
foo = math.cos(bar)
```

becomes *illegal*, as the `math` symbol will be not (recognized) in the `main.py` namespace.

Comment: Oh. Am I right to think that `my_own_module.math.sin(bar)` would work (without the `import math` in "main.py")?

Comment: Yes, you're right. `main.py` knows the name `my_own_module` which in turn recognized the `math` name (which in turn recognized the `cos`  name).

Answer (score 1):

This is not like, eg `#include` in C++. The import is *not* optional. Importing a module is required to be able to refer to its contents. This is true for every single file that does it.

Answer (score 0):

A good question. The short answer is yes, if you use a math function in a py file then you need to import the module at the top regardless of how many times its imported elsewhere.

It gets interesting when we throw a thrid file into the mix, lets call this "explanation.py"

And lets suppose that your "main.py" becomes "my_functions.py" and contains a function called foo:

```
#my_functions.py
import math
import my_own_module
def foo(bar):
    return math.cos(bar)
```

and in my_own_module.py:

```
#my_own_module.py
import math
def bar(foo):
    return math.sin(foo)
```

and finally explanation.py (new main())

```
#main.py
import my_functions
import my_own_module
bar = my_functions.foo(10)
foo =  my_own_module.bar(10)
print(foo)
print(bar)
```

Notice how you DO NOT need to add math if you call the functions imported from another file. I hope that might add further clarity to your enquiry :)

However it might be worth noting that this would exclude maths from the current namespace, therefore rendering any further calls to the math functions useless.