# Best practice for nested Python module imports with *

Tags: python, python-import

Earlier today I asked [a closely related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51956302/best-practice-for-nested-python-module-imports) and got great answers. But I'd really asked the wrong question. So I'll try again:

Suppose I have a Python module "main.py":

```
# main.py
import math                   # from the standard Python library
from my_own_module import *

...

foo = math.cos(bar)
```

And I also need to import the standard math module in "my_own_module.py":

```
# my_own_module.py
import math

...

baz = math.sin(qux)
```

In this case I think `import math` in "main.py" is redundant and can be omitted.

What's best practice in this case:

1. Omit `import math` from "main.py" becuase it's redundant? Or,
2. Keep `import math` in "main.py" to clarify that the code in that
   module requires it?

I suppose somebody will say "don't use `import *`".  In this case "my_own_module.py" is a personal library of small routines that I include in every Python project. (For example, I have my own `mkdir()` that doesn't complain if the directory already exists.) It seems very convenient to use `import *` here.

Comment: Why would you import something that needs not to be imported?

Comment: It really comes down to whether you consider `math` to be part of the "public interface" of `my_own_module`. Since you don't have an `__all__`, and it doesn't start with an underscore, the default answer is "yes", but the default doesn't really matter; it's entirely up to how you want to think about it.

Comment: Don't use `import *`. I see your rationalization and reject it. It doesn't matter whether it's "a personal library of small routines"; that doesn't change any of the reasons `import *` is a bad idea.

Comment: Also, the fact that you're using `import *` and don't have an `__all__` really means that, _either way_, your intentional is ambiguous to anyone but you. If you expect anyone else to ever read this code (or even yourself a year from now when you've forgotten this module), you should document which things are meant to be the "public interface", and using `__all__` is the simplest way to do that, and also one that the import system enforces.